# expected "string" for status 0 but got None

Tags: python

i get following error and i am not able to solve it:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/data/task-data/scarypython/tests.py", line 27, in test_scenario_2
> f"Expected 'Your Payment is unknown.' for payment status 0 but got: '{CheckoutService.get_payment_status(0)}'"
> AssertionError: None != 'Your Payment is unknown.' : Expected 'Your Payment is unknown.' for payment status 0 but got: 'None'

Code is:

```
class PaymentStatus:
    UNDEFINED = (0, None)
    PROCESSED = 100
    PAYED = 200
    DECLINED = 300


class CheckoutService(object):
    @staticmethod
    def add_payment_to_successful_payments(payment=None, successful_payments=None):
        if successful_payments is None:
            successful_payments = []
        successful_payments.append(payment)
        return successful_payments

    @staticmethod
    def get_payment_status(status_number):
        if status_number is PaymentStatus.PROCESSED:
            return "Your Payment is processed."
        if status_number is PaymentStatus.PAYED:
            return "Your Payment is payed."
        if status_number is PaymentStatus.DECLINED:
            return "Sorry your Payment was declined."
        if status_number is None or "":
            return "Your Payment is unknown."
```

Comment: Nowhere in your `get_payment_status` you handle the case that `status_number` is `0`.

Comment: Also, `if status_number is None or ""` is not going to work as your thinking it might

Comment: @CherryDT is correct but you also have an issue with `'{CheckoutService.get_payment_status(0)}'`. It looks like an f-string that wasn't evaluated. That's usually because you forgot to include the `f` before your opening quotation mark. So after you fix the handling of status `0`, you will also need to fix the f-string in your test.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify below block of code.

```
if status_number in [None, 0]:
            return "Your Payment is unknown."
```

Comment: Tuslyan That doesnt work.

Comment: @KaiE are you getting the same error ?

Comment: yes, thats true

Comment: Ok, please consider to implement @CherryDT suggestion(check your question comments) too and let us know.